# XmlEnumAttribute to Enum parse

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I have enum class that looks like this:

```
public enum StupidEnum
    {

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("01")]
        Item01,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("01_1")]
        Item01_1,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("01_11")]
        Item01_11,
}
```

And now I would like to get Item01_11 enum object by only giving 01_11 value.
In other words I have value from Xml Enum Attribute and as a result I would need enum object to be returned.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to decode `01_11` from your code instead of from deserializing the enum?

Comment: I'm getting string value from database that is in this form "01_11" and I would want to parse it to enum value StupidEnum.Item01_11

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get it working but it's not a very elegant solution. Since your attributes are dependent on XML serialization you'll need to read it that way. I'll post the working code, and the way I would recommend.

```
var testString = "01_1";
var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StupidEnum));
// XmlSerializer expects XML so wrap what you got in xml tags.
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"<StupidEnum>{testString}</StupidEnum>")))
    var item = (StupidEnum)xml.Deserialize(ms);
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Alternatively, you can cast the `enum` to an integral type and store that number then cast back to your `enum` when reading or use the enumerations own ability to parse a string and not rely on the xml serialization values as follows:

```
var testString = "Item01_1";  
// you can also just get the 01_1 and concatenate it to "Item" when parsing in the next line
var value = Enum.Parse(typeof(StupidEnum), testString);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Utility class and method like below:

```
public static class EnumUtilities
{
    public static T GetValueFromXmlEnumAttribute<T>(string value) where T : Enum
    {
        foreach (var field in typeof(T).GetFields())
        {
            if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
            typeof(XmlEnumAttribute)) is XmlEnumAttribute attribute)
            {
                if (attribute.Name == value)
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
            else
            {
                if (field.Name == value)
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Could not parse XmlEnumAttribute. Not found.", nameof(value));
    }
```

And call it like:

```
var result = EnumUtilities.GetValueFromXmlEnumAttribute<StupidEnum>("01");
```